# Spring boot admin: Client can't register with admin server over https

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, https, spring-boot-admin

I have a handful of spring-boot microservices which register themselves with spring-boot-admin (SBA). When I run the microservices and the SBA server locally, the clients are able to register themselves with the SBA server via HTTP.

When I deploy the apps to the Kubernetes cluster, registration with SBA is done via HTTPS (via an [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)) I get a `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException` in the logs

```
d.c.b.a.c.r.ApplicationRegistrator : Failed to register application as Application(name=my-app, managementUrl=https://my-app-dev.mydomain.com/actuator, healthUrl=https://my-app-dev.mydomain.com/actuator/health, serviceUrl=https://my-app-dev.mydomain.com) at spring-boot-admin ([https://my-admin-dev.mydomain.com/instances]): I/O error on POST request for "https://my-admin-dev.mydomain.com/instances": Received fatal alert: protocol_version; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version. Further attempts are logged on DEBUG level
```

In the microservices (the SBA clients) I'm using the following dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And the following in `application.yaml`

```
spring.boot.admin.client:
  url: "https://my-admin-dev.mydomain.com"
  instance.service-url: "https://my-app-dev.mydomain.com"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to poke into the `spring-boot-admin-starter-client` code. Firstly I started with `ApplicationRegistrator` from the log message which led me to an overridable `BlockingRegistrationClient` instance (yay!)

```java
public class SpringBootAdminClientAutoConfiguration {
    ...
    @Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
    @ConditionalOnBean(RestTemplateBuilder.class)
    public static class BlockingRegistrationClientConfig {
        @Bean
        @ConditionalOnMissingBean
        public BlockingRegistrationClient registrationClient(ClientProperties client) {
            RestTemplateBuilder builder = new RestTemplateBuilder().setConnectTimeout(client.getConnectTimeout())
                    .setReadTimeout(client.getReadTimeout());
            if (client.getUsername() != null && client.getPassword() != null) {
                builder = builder.basicAuthentication(client.getUsername(), client.getPassword());
            }
            return new BlockingRegistrationClient(builder.build());
        }
    }
```

Using [this post](https://medium.com/@itzgeoff/using-a-custom-trust-store-with-resttemplate-in-spring-boot-77b18f6a5c39) as I guide I was able to create a `RestTemplate` with the trust store loaded into the `SSLContext`. I could then override the `BlockingRegistrationClient` instance with my own which wrapped the custom `RestTemplate`.

```java
@Bean
public BlockingRegistrationClient registrationClient(
        @Value("${ssl.protocol}") String protocol,
        @Value("${ssl.trustStore.path}") String trustStorePath,
        @Value("${ssl.trustStore.password}") String trustStorePassword,
        ClientProperties client) throws Exception {

    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContextBuilder.create()
            .loadTrustMaterial(new File(trustStorePath), trustStorePassword.toCharArray())
            .setProtocol(protocol)
            .build();

    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
            .setSSLContext(sslContext)
            .build();

    RestTemplateBuilder builder = new RestTemplateBuilder()
            .setConnectTimeout(client.getConnectTimeout())
            .setReadTimeout(client.getReadTimeout())
            .requestFactory(() -> new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient));

    if (client.getUsername() != null && client.getPassword() != null) {
        builder = builder.basicAuthentication(client.getUsername(), client.getPassword());
    }
    return new BlockingRegistrationClient(builder.build());
}
```

application.yaml

```
ssl:
  protocol: TLSv1.2
  trustStore:
    path: "/opt/java/openjdk/lib/security/cacerts"
    password: "*****"
```